# Return a function with parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, pythonista

I am trying to make a function that returns itself with parameters.

```
Def a (x,y):
   *code*
   Return a(x,y)
```

this returns an error when I try to run it.

```
>>> a(1,2)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

What I want is

```
>>> a(1,2)
a(1,2)
```

It there a way to return the function with parameters?

I know it can be done but I don’t know how to do it

```
>>> datetime.time(0,0)
Datetime.time(0,0)
```

Edit:
Preferably I would like not to have to import any modules

Comment: You're getting the error because the function just keeps calling itself, until the maximum recursion depth (to prevent a stack overflow). Why would you want to this?

Comment: Do you mean `return 'a({x},{y})'.format(x=x, y=y)`...?

Comment: What you want to do is recursion without base condition? Please look into if this is exactly what you want to do.

Comment: That looks more like the output from a class `__repr__`

Comment: As @wjandrea is saying, it looks like you're after a `__repr__` from a class, not a function.

Comment: How do I use__repr__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what is "returned" when you call the following row:

```
>>> datetime.time(0,0)
Datetime.time(0,0)
```

The original call `datetime.time(0,0)` creates a `datatime`-object to the console. Because you're not saving the returned object, the console automatically calls for the `class-method` called `__repr__`.

To replicate the behavior we can create the following `class`:

```
>>> class a:
...   def __init__(self, x,y):
...     self.x = x
...     self.y = y
...   def __repr__(self):
...     return "a({},{})".format(self.x, self.y)
...
>>> a(1,2)
a(1,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have no valid return. The error means it calls itself so many times python just gives up.
Example (good) will end after ''num'' times:

```
def a(x, num):
  if num == 0:
    return x
  return a(x + 1, num - 1)
```

Example (bad) will never return anything else as itself:

```
def a(x, num):
  if num == 0:
    return x
  return a(x + 1, num)
```

Comment: This is also known as a "bootstrap condition" in the recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean you want it to return a string representation of the function as called:

```
def a (x,y):
   *code*
   return f"a({x},{y})"
```

Alternatively if you are not able to use f-strings:

```
def a (x,y):
   *code*
   return "a({x},{y})".format(x=x, y=y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a nested function or lambda ?

```
$ python -q
>>> def a(x,y):
...     def _a():
...             return x + y
...     return _a
... 
>>> a(1,2)
<function a.<locals>._a at 0x7f048329e560>
>>> a(1,2)()
3
```